# Loop into a List in a Map using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

Say I have a map like below

```
Map<String, Map<List<String>, Map<String,List<String>>> mapData= testMap();
```

request.setAttribute("mapData", mapData);

Now I want to access the highligted List and print the values using JSTL

I tried this

```
<c:forEach items="${mapData}" var="mapData">

    <c:forEach items="${mapData.value}" var="secondMapdata">
```

(I don't wanna loop through this map here, instead I only want to loop into List and print values)

Basically it should be like this (See highlighted text below)

```
<c:forEach items=**"${mapData.value.key}"** var="secondMapdata">
```

Comment: Please post real code which you copypasted unchanged from your working test environment. The `Map<String>,List<String>` is impossibly real.

Comment: @BalusC : I'm really sorry about the typo. I've corrected my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more iteration level.

```
<c:forEach items="${mapData}" var="mapData">
    <c:forEach items="${mapData.value}" var="secondMapdata">
        <c:forEach items="#{secondMapdata.key}" var="listItem">
```

Comment: Your code made me think to re-do my code. Thanks a lot BalusC. :)